# how to include a separate file containing functions for a class

Tags: c++, class, arduino

So i am making a library for a hardware to be used with arduino. Inside that class there are some hardware specific code that needs to included. To improve readability i would like to move the hardware specific functions to another file

```
//.h
class myClass(){

public:
    myClass();
    void controlGPIO();
    
};


//.cpp
myClass::myClass(){
   controlGPIO();
}

#ifdef HARDWAREA
#include "deviceA_hal.h"
#endif

#ifdef HARDWAREB
#include "deviceB_hal.h"
#endif


//deviceA_hal.h     HardwareA functions
#include <deviceA_specific_Library>
void myClass::controlGPIO(){
   // some code unique to hardwareA
}


//deviceB_hal.h     HardwareB functions
#include <deviceB_specific_Library>
void myClass::controlGPIO(){
   // some code unique to hardwareB
}
```

Is this possible ? Am i doing this correctly?

This would make adding more specific hardware easier and cleaner. Is there a more better way of doing it>?

Comment: `myClass::void controlGPIO()` is not valid C++; you might have meant `void myClass::controlGPIO()`. However, `myClass` doesn't declare a member named `controlGPIO`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ahhh i see the problem. I have made edits. Am i structuring the code correctly>?

Comment: `class myClass(){` is still not valid code.

Comment: It's one way to do it, I suppose. Personally, I'd make them "normal" .cpp files, and used project configuration to arrange for one or the other to be part of the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common is to do one .cpp with

```
#if defined(HARDWAREA)
#include "deviceA_hal.h"
#elif defined(HARDWAREB)
#include "deviceB_hal.h"
#endif

void myClass::controlGPIO(){
#if defined(HARDWAREA)
   // some code unique to hardwareA
#elif defined(HARDWAREB)
   // some code unique to hardwareB
#endif
}
```

this is simpler to maintain than two separate files